# Set State Item Back to Initial State without mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in React that I am updating in a form. This form already has initial values and I am wanting to update the form item in the state back to its initial value when the input is an empty `''`.

I am updating the state object immutably when the user is typing or updating the field as such:

```
handleInputChange = (name, {value}) => {

    if(value === '') {
      this.setInitialState(name);
    }

    let val = {...this.state, [name] : value}

    this.setState(val);
  }
```

the `setInitialState` function can take the name of the input field that is being updated. The problem is how can I set just the one item in state back to its initial value without updating the entire state object back to initial, and I am trying to do it immutably.

Here is that function:

```
 setInitialState = (val) => {
    let active = this.props.member.active;
    let age = this.props.member.age;
    let firstname = this.props.member.firstname;
    let lastname = this.props.member.lastname;
    let gender = this.props.member.gender;
    let id = this.props.member.id;
    let patientId = this.props.member.patientId;



  }
```

I have tried doing the following:

1. `this.props.member.${val}`
2. `this.props.member.val`

I have looked for other questions and places where they update the entire state object back to initial, but that is not what I want to do.

If you have a place to see how to do such I am also open to looking at that as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you access object property with a string:

```
this.props.member[val]
```

General example based on what you tried:

```
var obj = { foo: "bar" };
console.log(obj.foo); // "bar". This is dot notation.
console.log(obj["foo"]); // "bar". This is what you need here - bracket notation
console.log(obj."foo"); // Syntax error
console.log(obj.${"foo"}); // Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

If the property `name` received in `handleInputValue` corresponds to the property key of your `member.*` object keys, you can do something along these lines:

```js
handleInputChange(name, { value }) {
  if (value === '') {
    this.setState({
      [name]: this.props.member[name]
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }
}
```